# Installing php-decimal extension on laragon for php 7.2, The specified module could not be found. Extension decimal does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laragon

I am trying to install this extension

https://php-decimal.io/#installation

to my Windows 10 64bit operating system which uses Laragon as Apache,PHP,MySQL

as the installation instruction focus more on Linux

I make a research on internet to found out a way to install on windows and found out the procedure to install it is by

- downloading the decimal extension dll file from here https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/decimal/1.3.0/ and paste it into php extension directory
- then edit php.ini to include the php_decimal extension

upon doing this I stumble upon an error after executing 'php --re decimal' to check if the extension have been properly installed

> 

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'decimal' (tried: C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\decimal (The specified module could not be found.), C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\php_decimal.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
Exception:

Extension decimal does not exist

> 

i have tried restarting Laragon and using different version of pecl releases,

when i look at phpinfo() i am unable to see any php-decimal extension installed,

below is the code of the extension i put into php.ini

[code_extension_php_decimal.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMlEg.png)

and below is the error that appear

[error_extension_decimal_does_not_exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w3Fq.png)

my php version

[php_version_7.2.19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMZIb.png)

what process am I missing

what is the proper way to install this extension in windows

Thank you

Comment: i also found other installation instruction at here https://github.com/php-decimal/ext-decimal but i don't understand how to install based on the windows dll releases provided

Comment: You need to copy "libmpdec.dll" to "C:\Windows\System32"

Comment: Done copying to directory C:\Windows\System32 , restarted laragon but still same error appear

Comment: Finally fixed, the problem is just wrong version installed, need to use this for php 7.2 php_decimal-1.3.0-7.2-ts-vc15-x64, copy to C:\Windows\System32 and it works!, Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Laragon with PHP 7.2 VC15-x64 download this pecl release

https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/decimal/1.3.0/php_decimal-1.3.0-7.2-ts-vc15-x64.zip

extract then copy to directory

```
C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\ext
```

(this is the default php extension directory, type 'php -i|findstr extension_dir' to get dir if unsure)

also copy the `libmpdec.dll` file to `C:\Windows\System32`

restart Laragon and it should work,
use this command to check if it have been successfully installed

`php --re decimal`

for different php version use different pecl release, also check on which VC version and x32 or x64 to make sure you get the correct release version.